# Swift enable point - make a point be clickable again

Tags: swift, calculator, point, rpn

I am a beginner and I am building a RPN calculator. I have disabled the point key (not clickable anymore) if the digit situated in the display has already a point. How can I enable it again after having pressed the enter key? Because now, it stays disabled even if I enter another digit in the display. So if I clicked on the point key once for the first digit, I cannot add a point for the second digit of my operation.

I have that code for to add a point to a digit:

```
    @IBAction func floatingPoint(sender: UIButton) {
    labelDisplay.text = labelDisplay.text! + "."
    sender.enabled = false //not clickable if the digit as already a point  
}
```

I have that code for enter:

```
var enterPressed = false
@IBAction func Enter() {
    userHasStartedTyping = false
    self.calcEngine!.operandStack.append(displayValue)
    print("Operand Stack on engine = \(self.calcEngine!.operandStack)")
}
```

I have that code for the operation:

```
    @IBAction func operation(sender: UIButton) {
    let operation = sender.currentTitle!
    if userHasStartedTyping { 
        Enter()  
    }
    self.displayValue = (self.calcEngine?.operate(operation))!
    Enter() //


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add an `@IBOutlet` in your class, so you can access this button from various parts of your code, not just it's action method. For example, add this to the top of your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet var pointButton:UIButton!
```

Remember to connect the button to this outlet on your storyboard.

With that, you can re-enable the point button in your `Enter()` method for example. Like this:

```
pointButton:UIButton.enabled = true
```